# Are partitioned matrices and 4D matrices are the same from algebra point of view?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I need to implement some computational algorithm using TensorFlow. I've got partitioned (block) matrices in the description of my algorithm. But there are no explicit ways to construct these in TF. But TF deals a lot with multidimensional matrices and tensors. That's the reason why I ask this question and consider it to be algebra-specific and relevant.

Can I treat partitioned (block) matrices as 4D matrices in my computations?

P.S. Or I should have asked this question on StackOverflow rather than here?

Answer (score 1):

Partitioned matrices are algebraically equivalent to 4D matrices if and only if the blocks of the partitioned matrices all have the same dimension sizes. This is because we should be able to talk about the dimension sizes of the 4D matrix irrespective of a particular choice of any index. If the blocks are not all the same size, this would leave some indices in your 4D matrix that you think should exist, but do not. This is the exact same reason why all the rows of a matrix have the same length; it is this condition that allows us to permute the dimensions of the matrix in any way we like.

Tensors, under the typical physics definition, must be square as well; their indices must all belong to the same range ($1$ through $n$). However there are lots of different definitions of tensors, so you may not necessarily be thinking in this context. Either way, you still need the condition stated above (all possible tuples of indices are defined) to be true.